# devtools does not check if dependencies are already installed

Tags: r

I am using `devtools::install_url("pkg_url", dependencies = TRUE, upgrade = "always")` to install specific versions of packages in a singularity build file. However I noticed during the installation procedure that each time it is run for each package, it installs many of the same dependencies over again, even though this was installed for one of the previous packages (same versions). I am not 100% sure how `devtools::install_url()` works, but this is making the installation runtime very long. Is there a way to make it check for the presence of these packages before trying to install them?

Comment: `devtools` wraps `remotes`, which wraps `install.packages()`.  Perhaps manually identifying the dependenices might help?`tools::package_dependencies(pkgs, available.packages(), "most", "strong") |> unlist(use.names = F) |> (\(.) .[!duplicated(.)])()` where pkgs is a character vector of the packages you want to install

Comment: @DonaldSeinen thank you for this tip! Does this also work when I want to detect dependencies for specific versions of the R packages? Not sure if it's necessary, but I'd like to install the one's needed for the specific package version..

Comment: @Haakondas That code snippet does not consider versions of dependencies, but could certainly be tweaked to do so. Remains to decide whether that is desirable and worth the effort. Usually, (if indeed at all) packages specify a version number *greater than*, a catch-all that any later package versions should not break code. The explicit `==` is much less common, let alone a duplicate for different versions. You could `grep` the `packageDescription` of the dependencies. If any are found, I'd consider contacting `maintainer("pkg")` and drop that package until conflict is resolved.